# How to make a safe Array subset in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to make a safe way of splitting an array.

I know you can take a subset of an array doing something like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(arr[0..<3])
```

It will print `[1,2,3]`

If you try the following on that same `arr`

```
print(arr[3..<9])
```

The program will crash

I want to make an array extension that will instead of crashing, yield as many of the elements as it can so it would print
`[4,5]`

```
subscript(safe range: Range) -> Element? {

}
```

Comment: You're not splitting the array, you're creating a slice (ie a view into the original array). What do you intend to do with it? Do you need the subset to be a _copy_ of a part of the original array?

Comment: It's just an array of `Double` types so it doesn't matter if its a copy or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(safe range: Range<Index>) -> ArraySlice<Element>? {
        if range.endIndex > endIndex {
            if range.startIndex >= endIndex {return nil}
            else {return self[range.startIndex..<endIndex]}
        }
        else {
            return self[range]
        }
    }
}

let a = [1,2,3]
a[safe: 1...3] // [2,3]
```

**Edit**: given the comment that the start index might not be the beginning of the array, I've amended so that the returned slice will always begin at startIndex even if the endIndex goes beyond bounds of the Array (unless start index is after endIndex of Array in which case nil is returned).

Comment: Could you please explain what is the significant of safe keyword here! Thank you.

Comment: It's just an external parameter name.

Comment: Exactly as @MarcusRossel states. We need something to distinguish a `safe` subscript from a regular (Array) subscript otherwise the compiler will not be able to infer whether we intend to use the regular subscript for an Array or our own extension.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But also I was wondering, why don't you make it return Array right away?

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Updated to a more straight forward version.

Just made for the practice. Same `safe` naming as the others used for clarity; note that it does not return nil but an empty array for out of bounds indexing, that avoids null checks in the consuming code for many cases.

```
extension Array {
    subscript(safe range: Range<Index>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        return self[min(range.startIndex, self.endIndex)..<min(range.endIndex, self.endIndex)]
    }
}

let a = [1,2,3]
a[safe: 1..<17] // [2,3]
a[safe: 4..<17] // []
a[safe: 1..<2]  // [2]
```

...or an alternate - more straight forward - version;

Comment: Method never returns nil, so `?` can be deleted.

Comment: @sketchyTech Thanks, started off with nil return, but figured it would be inconvenient to use a nil check instead of just using an empty array. Forgot the `?` though :)

Comment: No problem, this is a fun solution but I think the Swift police would probably arrest you for the amount complexity involved. `dropFirst` is O(n) and `prefix` is O(maxLength).

Comment: @sketchyTech The alternate version should be doing better.

Comment: A neat one-liner, looks great. You can strip out two uses of `self` to make it even more compact ... I've taken the liberty of editing these out myself,

Answer (score 4):

You can use the

```
extension RandomAccessIndexType {
    @warn_unused_result
    public func advancedBy(n: Self.Distance, limit: Self) -> Self
}
```

method to limit the given range to the valid range of the given array:

```
extension Array {

    public subscript (safe subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {

        let from = startIndex.advancedBy(subRange.startIndex, limit: endIndex)
        let to = startIndex.advancedBy(subRange.endIndex, limit: endIndex)
        return self[from ..< to]
    }
}


let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(arr[safe: 3..<10]) // [4, 5]
print(arr[safe: 9..<10]) // []
```

**Update for Swift 3:** Indexing collections has changed a lot.
Now you can use the `index(...)` methods defined in the 
`BidirectionalIndexable` protocol:

```
extension Array {

    public subscript (safe subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {

        let from = index(startIndex, offsetBy: subRange.lowerBound, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        let to = index(startIndex, offsetBy:  subRange.upperBound, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        return self[from ..< to]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Please let me know what is wrong here, thanks!

Comment: @sketchyTech: Thanks for the edit suggestion, I appreciate it. But if the intention is to *"yield as many of the elements as it can"* then – in my opinion – it makes more sense to return a (possibly empty) ArraySlice and not an *optional* ArraySlice.

Comment: It was purely to place it in line with the OP's code. I do think this is a better answer than mine and should probably be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer an empty collection over an optional collection. This works well with swift 4.

```
extension Array {
    /*
     Safe array access via range, accounting for array bounds
     examples:
     [1, 2, 3][0...6] -> []
     [1, 2, 3][0...1] -> [1, 2]
     */
   subscript(safe range: Range<Index>) -> [Element] {
        guard
            range.startIndex >= self.startIndex,
            range.endIndex <= self.endIndex
            else {
                return []
        }

        return Array(self[range])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on `Array`'s `startIndex`:

> Always zero, which is the index of the first element when non-empty.

`startIndex` can therefore be assumed to be the index of the first element (if there is one).

```
extension Array {
    subscript(safe range: Range<Index>) -> [Element]? {
        guard range.startIndex >= self.startIndex else { return nil }
        guard range.endIndex <= self.endIndex else { return nil }

        return Array(self[range])
    }
}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][safe: 1..<4] // [2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][safe: 1...7] // nil
```

Answer (score 0):

We can generalise Martin's fine solution for `CollectionType`s as follows. Also, I think I would be a little more comfortable with a signature like `take(_: Range<Index>)` since `take(_: Int)` traditionally has similarly forgiving out of range semantics (in contrast to collections' `subscript` method):

```
public extension CollectionType where Index.Distance : protocol<IntegerLiteralConvertible, Comparable> {

    public func take(range: Range<Index>) -> SubSequence {

        let dFrom = startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        let dTo = startIndex.distanceTo(range.endIndex)

        let from = dFrom <= 0 ? startIndex : startIndex.advancedBy(dFrom, limit: endIndex)
        let to = dTo <= 0 ? startIndex : startIndex.advancedBy(dTo, limit: endIndex)

        return self[from..<to]
    }
}

public extension CollectionType {
    public var array: [Generator.Element] { return Array(self) }
}

let collection = 1...5

collection.take(9...10).array           // []
collection.take(1...3).array            // [2, 3, 4]
collection.take((-3)...10).array        // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
collection.take((-5)...(-2)).array      // []
```

The constraint `Index.Distance : protocol<IntegerLiteralConvertible, Comparable>` is only needed in order to gracefully deal with ranges of indices smaller than `startIndex`...

Note that applying this to `String.characters` would require:

```
let s = "random string"
s.characters.take(s.startIndex.advancedBy(3)...s.startIndex.advancedBy(5)).array // ["d", "o", "m"]
```

Not so nice. However, we could provide a `take(_: Range<Int>)` alternative in addition to the more general code above:

```
public extension CollectionType where Index.Distance == Int {

    public func take(range: Range<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let from = range.startIndex <= 0 ? startIndex : startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex, limit: endIndex)
        let to = range.endIndex <= 0 ? startIndex : startIndex.advancedBy(range.endIndex, limit: endIndex)
        return self[from..<to]
    }
}

s.characters.take(3...5).array // ["d", "o", "m"]
```